# Creating an index in a SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a requirement to create an index on a table in sql server for optimising a particular SP. Is that okay if I create the index in the SP, do my tasks and in the end drop the index so that the other SPs are not effected by my index? Will it disturb the equilibrium or any cons of this technique? The table contains 3 million rows.

Comment: If the index is beneficial, why drop it at all?

Comment: @md4 While it may be beneficial for the particular SP's operation, it could substantially affect insert/update performance for other dependencies.

Comment: @EricHauenstein, I'm aware of what *could* happen, I'm curious as to the OP's specific circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You would drop/re-add an index for data importing.  That would be the only reason to do it on a "real" and "live" table.

Otherwise, indexes are kinda meant (IMHO) to be created and ***left alone***.

If you're just dealing with data, consider "experimenting with"....a #tempTable index.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end


CREATE TABLE #Holder
(ID INT )
   

/* simulate your insert */
INSERT INTO #HOLDER (ID) 
select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4

   
/* CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID) */
   
CREATE INDEX IDX_TempHolder_ID ON #Holder (ID)


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Holder') IS NOT NULL
begin
    drop table #Holder
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend it.

In your test environment I would create the index and see how much it slows down inserts. If there is no appreciable affect (or an acceptable effect), then I would simply create the index and leave it.

It's probably worth your while popping over to BrentOzar.com and looking at their sp_BlitzIndex stored procedure and doing some diagnostics.

Comment: I don't want the index anywhere else except my 1 SP. So will it hamper anything if I drop it after doing my work? Is there any harm in dropping the index after use( creating a temporary index)?

Comment: Why?   

I normally wouldn't recommend creating indexes on the fly like this because you will:

a) Slow down the performance of your sp.
b) Lock the table while the index is being created.

Is there a chance that a process will kick off the SP more than once concurrently?  If this is the case then the second will fail as the index will already exist.